# Do Daredevil's foes know about his condition?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, daredevil-tv

I recently watched the two Daredevil seasons and was wondering if Daredevil's enemies know that he is blind.

In the last episode it was apparent that the ninjas knew about his blindness as they did not use their weapons to not give away their position.

Comment: do the ninjas not count as his foes for some reason?

Comment: I think the ninjas do not count because I believe they knew about the blind kid Stick was training.

Comment: so you're counting his foes as... random thugs and frank castle?

Comment: Frank Castle, Wilson Fisk, the Police officer if you want, Melvin Potter could also count

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86677/do-daredevils-enemies-know-that-hes-blind

Comment: @FranciscoV. `I think the ninjas do not count because I believe they knew about the blind kid Stick was training.` If you define "foes" as "foes who do not know he's blind" (since you exclude the ninjas on the basis that they knew he was blind), then **of course his "foes" don't know he's blind**.

Comment: I'm not that far into it but they keep calling it a mask, not a blindfold. Ninjas don't count because not ghosting yourself is part of the job. Could've realized he was better at it then them and just has his eyes closed, and they needed to step it up to his level *real* quick.

Comment: [Ninja Scroll: Jubei vs. Utsutsu Mujuro Fight Breakdown](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xrhuErO31x8)

Answer (score 1):

Well, as of 2024 (before Born Again), the people who do know Daredevil is blind and/or Matt Murdock are - (spoilers ahead)

1. The ninjas, and extrapolating it, the Hand (which is finished as of now) (**FOE**)
2. Frank Castle (**FOE**, though he does and might team up with him in some cases)
3. Wilson Fisk (might be reaching here, but Vanessa Fisk may join the list) (**FOE**)
4. Foggy Nelson
5. Karen Page
6. Jessica Jones
7. Luke Cage
8. Danny Rand
9. Agent Ray Nadeem
10. Stick
11. Elektra (in the MCU, a **FOE**, but we don't know where she is as of now, if not dead)
12. Jennifer Walters (She-Hulk)

This list might also contain Peter Parker, Happy Hogan and Aunt May, but it isn't confirmed if they know Matt is Daredevil yet, but they of course know he's blind. (May sure won't know now)

Comment: And how many of those are his *foes*?

Comment: @F1Krazy put that in now!